# Casting an object in inheritance, why this output?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, output

#### There is class T:

```
public class T
{
    protected String name;
    public T(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return "T:"+this.name;
    }
}
```

#### Class G:

```
public class G extends T
{
     public G(String name)
     {
          super(name);
     }
     public String toString()
     {
          return "G:" + super.toString();
     }
}
```

When I run

```
G a3 = new G("me");
System.out.println((T)a3)
```

It prints `G:T:me`.

I don't understand why. I thought it would print `T:me`. I claim this because it was casted as object T. And therefore, using the `toString()` of class T. However, I'm wrong. Why does this happen?

I know there are not good names for classes, it's a question about understanding polymorphism and inheritance, not just to write a specific code I need.

Comment: What does `super.toString()` do?

Comment: Are you asking me a question for you to understand or a question so I  can think about it? With that code it will activate the method toString() of the class T.

Comment: So you would think about it.

Comment: @Pillar Oh so am I right?

Comment: The part I don't understand is **why** it doesn't activate the method of toString() on the class T.

Comment: Yes, which you also see from your current output. Your object is of dynamic type `a3`. The cast doesn't change that. When `println` eventually invokes `toString` on it, its `G`'s implementation that gets invoked, appending the `G`, then `super.toString()` gets invoked, calling `T`'s implementation, which  returns `T:me` that gets appended to the `G`.

Comment: Because of dynamic dispatch, polymorphism, whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108422/discussion-between-pichi-wuana-and-pillar).

Comment: @Pillar what is the difference between `System.out.println(a3);` and `System.out.println((T)a3);`?

Comment: There is none. `println` expects `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crucial point here is **a cast does not change the object in any way**. All it does is allow you to treat it as a different (compatible) type. The objects functionality stays **exactly the same**.

The code:

```
 public String toString()
 {
      return "G:" + super.toString();
 }
```

completely removes the old `toString` to a point where it is no longer accessable at all (mostly).

Comment: What do you mean treat it as a different compatible type?

Comment: @PichiWuana - compatible means you can cast up or down but you cannot cast across. E.g. You **can** cast any object up to `(Object)` or down to it's actual type but not across to something like `Integer` or `HashMap`.

Comment: If `a4` is a **T** object, what would happen with `System.out.println((G)a4);`?

Comment: @PichiWuana - It will **always** call the method of the actual object it has, not the type it is pretending to be. In your case if `a4` is a `T` then `System.out.println((G)a4)` will invoke `T.toString()` every time.

Comment: But can you cast it to T's *son*?

Answer (score 4):

The method `toString()` in class G *overrides* the method in class T, so it gets chosen. The static type of the object is used by the compiler to decide which *overload* of a method to use. It could only make a difference if there were two *different* `toString()` methods defined on T to choose from, and / or G defined another `toString()` overload somehow - although it's not really possible when there are no arguments to the method.

Answer (score 3):

> G a3 = new G("me");

This line calls both the construcotrs of T as well as G.

```
public T(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
    // so, this.name gets initialised to me.
}

public G(String name)
 {
      super(name);
 }
```

Now, since you have overridden the `toString()` method, ***but***, calling the `System.out.println((T)a3)` doesn't change the type of a3 from Object to any other type. It makes possible printing `a3` as an object(since println() also accepts parameter of type Object), but, a3 is still being overridden in both the classes.

So, your `toString()` method will be called, thereby leading to printing of `G:T:me.`.